# how to add list to many=True serializer in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have list [1, 2, 3]
and TestModel queryset

`[ {'pk':1,'text':'one'}, {'pk':2,'text':'two'}, {'pk':3,'text':'three'}]`

and I have model and serializer like following

```
class TestMode(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class TestModelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('pk', 'text')
```

I want to make data like

```
[{'pk':1, 'text':'one', 'number':1}, {..., 'number':2}, {..., 'number':3}]
```

I make another serializer

```
class WrapperSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    number = serializer.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('pk', 'text')
```

I try to like following, but i think it's not cool

```
serialized_data = TestModelSerializer(qs, many=True).data

for index, data in enumerate(serializerd_data):
    data['number'] = list[index]

serializer = WrapperSerializer(serialized_data, many=True)
```

How can i do that??? i don't have another idea... please help me

Comment: where does `number` come from? Your model has no `number` field. Is number the same as pk?

Comment: I am making friendship relation and there is grade in relationship. I'd like to include all from_user, to_user in the friend list. And when I call up the list of friends of object, I want to bring a grade too.

Comment: now you're talking about relationships and "grade" which are shown nowhere in your question. when asking a question on SO, please always show your real models and real data, that will make it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve. Don't try to replace code with dummy code, because if I try to reproduce your code by copying `TestModel` there's no way I can get a `number` from it, i.e. no way I can give you an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a calculated value (read-only) to your serializer, you have two options:

- On the model, define a `@property` `number`:

  ```
  @property
  def number(self):
      return self.friends.count()  # or whatever you need to calculate the number
  ```

  Then in your serializer, you can just use `number` as any other field, but need to specify the type of serializer (e.g. `IntegerField`).
- on the serializer use a `SerializerMethodField` as described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

  ```
  number = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_number(self, obj):
      return obj.friends.count()
  ```